# How is reputation grouped in the achievements dialog (trophy menu)?

Tags: support, reputation, achievements-dialog

> [image]

In the above image, there are two groups for my post on Puzzling.SE. The `+35` one contains 7 upvotes (it's a question), and the `+4` one contains an accept and an approved suggested edit.

I searched for "reputation group" and all the questions I found are about grouping in profile page, not top-bar menu.

How is reputation grouped in this menu? It seems to be different from how it is in the profile page.

Comment: @rene Both events in the `+4` entry happened among the 7 votes, so if group by time, the `+35` should be splitted up into 3 or more entries of `+5`, `+10` and `+15`, etc.

Comment: Yeah, it is more complex then that and caching. There are also "reputation grouping" batches run now and then. They consolidate votes. I expect achievements and your profile to be cached differently so that they don't match is by design.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's grouped by the 'target' of the vote. The final suggested edit review is stored as a *vote* (by the last reviewer) on the edited post (that's why you lose 2 reputation if a user is deleted); accepting an answer is stored as an 'accept vote' on the answer, not the question.

But it's grouped the same way in [your profile](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/44061/ibug?tab=reputation):

[image]

(It might not be if some events happened *before* and some happened *after* your last visit to the reputation tab; in that case, the 'new' events are shown separately from the 'old' ones. Refreshing the page solves that.)

Comment: That won't be 100% correct, because [users have reported](/q/147683) that the profile page sometimes split upvotes into several groups in the same day, while in this menu it never does so.

Comment: That might be a bug then (not sure if it's still a problem, that's a bug report from 2012). I was already writing a new last paragraph when you commented; this explains everything as far as I've experience this.